# Custom Fields and Extended properties - Are they Same?

Tags: google-api, gdata-api, google-contacts-api, google-data-api

There is an option to "Add a custom field" in Google Contacts web page, when we create/edit a contact.

Using Google Contact API v3.0, we can add "extended properties" using 'gd:extendedProperty' xml-element.

Are these two pointing to the same field. When I create an extended property via API, I am not seeing that field/value in the Google contacts web page view.

I get a feeling that, the gd:extendedProperty is solely for API based manipulation purpose. Is it right?

In that case, is it possible to create a "Custom Field" via API and I want that field/value to be shown in the Google Contacts web page.

Comment: Custom fields and Extended properties are different. If you want to add custom field to the contact, you have to add this line <gContact:userDefinedField key='' value='CustomValue1'/> in the xml you are using for adding contact. I tried the scenario and it worked for me.

Comment: I am having a similar problem: I need to change the value of a Google Contacts "Custom Field" via the API. Yet, I don't see any of the custom fields appearing in the contact I am receiving from the API, but therefore I see an extended property that I don't see in the website.

Comment: I just added the line <gContact:userDefinedField key='' value='CustomValue1'/>  while trying to add new contact, and it worked for me